# Ошибка собрки buildozer с модулем cryptography

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, apk

При сборке под android apk фалйа с использование cryptography идёт следующая ошибка.

```
c/_cffi_backend.c:4197:31: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *'
      discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
        *p_printable_filename = PyText_AsUTF8(s);
                              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c/_cffi_backend.c:5911:9: warning: 'ffi_prep_closure' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    if (ffi_prep_closure(closure, &cif_descr->cif,
        ^
/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/libffi/include/ffi.h:339:18: note: 
      'ffi_prep_closure' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  __attribute__((deprecated))
                 ^
In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:7370:
In file included from c/cffi1_module.c:20:
c/call_python.c:20:30: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
    builtins = tstate->interp->builtins;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Include/pystate.h:20:8: note: 
      forward declaration of 'struct _is'
struct _is;
       ^
In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:7370:
In file included from c/cffi1_module.c:20:
c/call_python.c:160:39: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
    new1 = PyThreadState_GET()->interp->modules;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Include/pystate.h:20:8: note: 
      forward declaration of 'struct _is'
struct _is;
       ^
In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:7370:
In file included from c/cffi1_module.c:20:
c/call_python.c:249:63: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
        if (externpy->reserved1 != PyThreadState_GET()->interp->modules) {
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Include/pystate.h:20:8: note: 
      forward declaration of 'struct _is'
struct _is;
       ^
2 warnings and 3 errors generated.
error: command '/home/overlord/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/overlord/anaconda3/envs/Brotherhood/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/overlord/anaconda3/envs/Brotherhood/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1199, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 671, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 155, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 209, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 580, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1009, in build_arch
    self.build_compiled_components(arch)
  File "/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1021, in build_compiled_components
    _env=env, *self.setup_extra_args)
  File "/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 180, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/overlord/anaconda3/envs/Brotherhood/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/overlord/anaconda3/envs/Brotherhood/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/overlord/anaconda3/envs/Brotherhood/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

  STDOUT:
running build_ext
building '_cffi_backend' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/c
/home/overlord/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi22 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target armv7a-linux-androideabi22 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/libffi/include -I/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Include -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=22 -I/home/overlord/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -I/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Brotherhood/include/python3.8 -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/c/_cffi_backend.o
c/_cffi_backend.c:4197:31: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *'
      discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
        *p_printable_filename = PyText_AsUTF8(s);
                              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c/_cffi_backend.c:5911:9: warning: 'ffi_prep_closure' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    if (ffi_prep_closure(closure, &cif_descr->cif,
        ^
/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/libffi/include/ffi.h:339:18: note: 
      'ffi_prep_closure' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  __attribute__((deprecated))
                 ^
In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:7370:
In file included from c/cffi1_module.c:20:
c/call_python.c:20:30: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
    builtins = tstate->interp->builtins;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Include/pystate.h:20:8: note: 
      forward declaration of 'struct _is'
struct _is;
       ^
In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:7370:
In file included from c/cffi1_module.c:20:
c/call_python.c:160:39: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
    new1 = PyThreadState_GET()->interp->modules;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Include/pystate.h:20:8: note: 
      forward declaration of 'struct _is'
struct _is;
       ^
In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:7370:
In file included from c/cffi1_module.c:20:
c/call_python.c:249:63: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
        if (externpy->reserved1 != PyThreadState_GET()->interp->modules) {
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Include/pystate.h:20:8: note: 
      forward declaration of 'struct _is'
struct _is;
       ^
2 warnings and 3 errors generated.
error: command '/home/overlord/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Сведения о системе

```
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/HackerSpace:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1064,unix/HackerSpace:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1064'
#     SNAP_REVISION = '196'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     CONDA_EXE = '/home/overlord/anaconda3/bin/conda'
#     _CE_M = ''
#     TERMINAL_EMULATOR = 'JetBrains-JediTerm'
#     SNAP_USER_COMMON = '/home/overlord/snap/pycharm-professional/common'
#     LANGUAGE = ''
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     LC_NAME = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     SNAP_INSTANCE_KEY = ''
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = '/usr/share/xsessions/plasma'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-professional_pycharm-professional.desktop'
#     GTK_RC_FILES = '/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/overlord/.gtkrc:/home/overlord/.config/gtkrc'
#     EDITOR = '/usr/bin/nano'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'canberra-gtk-module'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PWD = '/home/overlord/PycharmProjects/Brotherhood/BrotherhoodClient'
#     LOGNAME = 'overlord'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'KDE'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     CONDA_PREFIX = '/home/overlord/anaconda3/envs/Brotherhood'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/.Xauthority'
#     DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID = 'HackerSpace;1587486205;215031;487059_TIME37715611'
#     SNAP_CONTEXT = 'rSLZ3R5Dm3UKxQfhTpkZrEgxArrX5USoloqsEG66-lekm5O2tE96'
#     GTK2_RC_FILES = '/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/overlord/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/overlord/.config/gtkrc-2.0'
#     HOME = '/home/overlord'
#     LANG = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     LC_PAPER = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.pdf=00;32:*.ps=00;32:*.txt=00;32:*.patch=00;32:*.diff=00;32:*.log=00;32:*.tex=00;32:*.doc=00;32:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'KDE'
#     SNAP_ARCH = 'amd64'
#     SNAP_INSTANCE_NAME = 'pycharm-professional'
#     SNAP_USER_DATA = '/home/overlord/snap/pycharm-professional/196'
#     CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER = '(Brotherhood) '
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     SNAP_REEXEC = ''
#     KDE_SESSION_UID = '1000'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     _CE_CONDA = ''
#     USER = 'overlord'
#     SNAP = '/snap/pycharm-professional/196'
#     CONDA_SHLVL = '2'
#     KDE_SESSION_VERSION = '5'
#     PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN = '/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket'
#     SNAP_COMMON = '/var/snap/pycharm-professional/common'
#     SNAP_VERSION = '2020.1'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '2'
#     SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH = '/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32:/var/lib/snapd/void'
#     SNAP_COOKIE = 'rSLZ3R5Dm3UKxQfhTpkZrEgxArrX5USoloqsEG66-lekm5O2tE96'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     XDG_VTNR = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
#     QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON = '1'
#     SNAP_DATA = '/var/snap/pycharm-professional/196'
#     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE = '/home/overlord/anaconda3/bin/python'
#     MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH = '/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000/snap.pycharm-professional'
#     CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV = 'Brotherhood'
#     LC_TIME = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     SNAP_NAME = 'pycharm-professional'
#     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '0'
#     XCURSOR_THEME = 'breeze_cursors'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/home/overlord/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     KDE_FULL_SESSION = 'true'
#     BROWSER = '/usr/bin/firefox'
#     PATH = '/home/overlord/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/overlord/anaconda3/envs/Brotherhood/bin:/home/overlord/anaconda3/condabin:/home/overlord/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin'
#     GTK_USE_PORTAL = '1'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     MAIL = '/var/spool/mail/overlord'
#     CONDA_PREFIX_1 = '/home/overlord/anaconda3'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     OLDPWD = '/snap/pycharm-professional/196/bin'
#     _ = '/home/overlord/anaconda3/envs/Brotherhood/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/overlord/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/overlord/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/overlord/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '22'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

---

UPD: пример для воспроизведения
**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

import cryptography

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        l = Label(text='Hello!',
                  font_size=150)
        f.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(l)
        return f


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

**buildozer.spec**

```
[app]
title = Example
package.name = Example
package.domain = example.org
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py,kv,crt,key,json,jpeg,png,json,token
source.exclude_exts = spec
source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin
version = 0.4
requirements = python3,pillow,pycparser,cryptography,cython,attrs,kivy,kivymd,twisted,zope.interface,pyopenssl
orientation = all
osx.python_version = 3
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.1
fullscreen = 0
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA
android.api = 27
android.minapi = 22
android.sdk = 28
android.ndk = 19b
android.ndk_api = 22
exitandroid.private_storage = False
android.accept_sdk_license = True
android.arch = armeabi-v7a
[buildozer]
log_level = 2
warn_on_root = 0
```

Comment: Какой файл? Сделайте минимальный воспроизводимый проект

Comment: Добавил минимальный воспроизводимый проект

Comment: Как сборку делаете?

Comment: buildozer android debug

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, исправьте название приложения.

```
ExamplelApp -> ExampleApp
```

Далее, я решил попробовать запустить Ваше приложение. Делаю это так:

Создал файл `main.py` с приложением.

Устанавливаю все требуемые пакеты как сказано [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201612/buildozer-command-not-found):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential ccache git zlib1g-dev libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 openjdk-8-jdk unzip ant ccache autoconf libtool
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev
pip install cython
pip install buildozer
buildozer init
```

Устанавливаю `cython`:

```
pip install cython
```

Запускаю команду, которую Вы обозначили. Сборка проходит. Приложение лежит в `bin/`

Последние несколько строк сборки:

```
[INFO]:    # Found APK file: /home/eurvanov/python/fless.pro/grader-v2-deploy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/build/outputs/apk/debug/myapp__armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
[INFO]:    # Add version number to APK
[INFO]:    # APK renamed to myapp__armeabi-v7a-debug-0.1-.apk
[DEBUG]:   -> running cp /home/eurvanov/python/fless.pro/grader-v2-deploy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/build/outputs/apk/debug/myapp__armeabi-v7a-debug.apk myapp__armeabi-v7a-debug-0.1-.apk
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No compiled python is present to zip, skipping.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Android packaging done!
# APK myapp__armeabi-v7a-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk available in the bin directory
```

Comment: Было бы действительно чудесно, если бы всё прошо так же гладко и на arch подобном manjaro, однако там эта ошибка всё ещё остаётся. cython последней версии. В примере так же поправил имя приложения, однако, лучше от этого не стало.

Comment: @Overlordix что есть manjaro?

Comment: Правда, я модуль cryptography выпилил, так как он у вас нигде не использовался? На том примере, что Вы привели, у Вас также ошибка?

Comment: manajro - Дистрибутив Linux основанный на Arch Linux.

Comment: Сам же cryptography не используется в примере ввиду того, что на то он и пример. Вопрос именно в ошибке при сборке самого apk, при использовании cryptography как зависимости, а не чтения кода.
Без использования данного модуля и у меня проходит успешно сборка, но стоит только его добавить, как выходит эта ошибка.